# ‘struct' declared inside parameter list

Tags: c, compiler-construction, error-handling, struct, header

Here's my header file that was included in another file but not yet used:

```
#define ksm_read 0X01
#define ksm_rdwr 0x00

struct ksm_info_t {
    uint ksmsz; //size of shared mem
    int cpid;   //pid of the creator
    int mpid;   //pid of the last modifier
    uint attached_nr; //number of attached processes
    uint atime; //last attached time
    uint dtime; //last deattach time
    uint total_shrg_nr; //total number of existing shared regions
    uint total_shpg_nr; //total number of existing shared pages
};

int ksmget(char* name, uint size);
int ksmattach(int hd, int flag);
int ksmdetach(int hd);
int ksminfo(int hd, struct ksminfo_t* info);
int ksmdelete(int hd);
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
> ksm.h:18: error: ‘struct ksminfo_t’ declared inside parameter list
> ksm.h:18: error: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is prob
```

Comment: Whenever I get an error about declarations, first thing I do is go character by character through the name of variable in the error and the line in my code. Slightly OCD but it tends to catch things like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo, should be `struct ksm_info_t`, not `struct ksminfo_t`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an underscore:

```
int ksminfo(int hd, struct ksminfo_t* info);
```

should be

```
int ksminfo(int hd, struct ksm_info_t* info);
```